# Passing a function variable to the by option in `inner_join()` to join two tables by different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

My colleague and I are working on a function that takes two tables, does some simple data processing and then uses `inner_join()` to join them together. One of the tables will come from an upstream portion of a workflow and will have a column of ids named in a specific way. The other table is provided by the user and while it will have the same column of ids, it might not be named the same. Therefore we used the `by = c("table1colname" = "table2colname")` option in `inner_join()` but we got an error saying that there is a problem with `column.name` and that the "Join" columns must be present in the data... both of which are. We've checked syntax and tried a couple different ways of defining `column.name` in the function but have yet to figure out the problem.

The following is a simple example that replicates the error:

```r
library(tidyverse)

X <- tribble(
  ~chickens, ~ducks, ~town,
  12, 62, "Burlington",
  18, 83, "Houston",
  34, 65, "Cincinatti"
)

Y <- tribble(
  ~chickens, ~ducks, ~city,
  34, 54, "Burlington",
  54, 29, "Cincinatti",
  12, 89, "Albuquerque"
)

join_fowl <- function(tab_1 = NULL, tab_2 = NULL, column.name = c("join_by")) {
  
  joined_fowl <- tab_1 %>% inner_join(tab_2, by = c(column.name = "city"))

}

join_fowl(X, Y, column.name = "town")
#> Error: Join columns must be present in data.
#> x Problem with `column.name`.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this an issue with the way `dplyr` is evaluating `column.name` or something else entirely? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also `rename` the dataset column name

```
library(dplyr)
join_fowl <- function(tab_1 = NULL, tab_2 = NULL, column.name = c("join_by")) {
     tab_1 %>%
     inner_join(tab_2 %>% rename(!! column.name := "city"), 
         by =  column.name)

  }

join_fowl(X, Y, column.name = "town")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  chickens.x ducks.x town       chickens.y ducks.y
#       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         12      62 Burlington         34      54
#2         34      65 Cincinatti         54      29
```

---

Or we can create a named list in `by` with `:=` using `dplyr::lst` and then `unlist` it

```
join_fowl <- function(tab_1 = NULL, tab_2 = NULL, column.name = c("join_by")) {
       tab_1 %>%
       inner_join(tab_2, by = unlist(lst(!! column.name := "city")))
 
 }

join_fowl(X, Y, column.name = "town")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  chickens.x ducks.x town       chickens.y ducks.y
#       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
#1         12      62 Burlington         34      54
#2         34      65 Cincinatti         54      29
```

Answer (score 2):

The `by` argument uses a named vector so you could use `setNames()`:

```
join_fowl <- function(tab_1 = NULL, tab_2 = NULL, column.name = c("join_by")) {
  
  joined_fowl <- tab_1 %>% inner_join(tab_2, by = setNames("city", column.name))
  return(joined_fowl)
  
}
    
join_fowl(X, Y, column.name = "town")

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  chickens.x ducks.x town       chickens.y ducks.y
       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>   <dbl>
1         12      62 Burlington         34      54
2         34      65 Cincinatti         54      29
```